# Parcel Width by Line Segment Closest to Street

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6, parcel

My end goal is to calculate parcel widths (polygons). I use ArcGIS 10.6 but can also use QGIS if a solution requires it.

- *please note not all parcels are regular shapes, some are irregular*

I converted my parcel polygons to polylines and calculated the length of each line segment.

I am now stuck on how to select the line segment closest to the road center-line and use that length for the parcel width (either temp join and add new field with field calculator or???)
the image below is an example, the selected segments would be the ones I need to use length of and write that value to its corresponding polygon feature-- road center line is the dark grey)

For parcels on corners that have two line segments facing two different streets I need to find the smallest value (narrowest segment)--

[image]

I have over 30k parcels I cannot manually go through each polygon and measure the width and add a value to a field.

Comment: I suggest looking for information on _frontage_. See [Finding parcel polygon features with frontage on multiple streets using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13473/finding-parcel-polygon-features-with-frontage-on-multiple-streets-using-arcgis-d), for example.

Comment: Since you need more than one nearest line segment for some of the parcels, you can use a NearTable. Do you already have some indicator in your dataset for corner parcels? If so, then I would use a selection by attribute to narrow down the parcel lines to each individual parcel, then use near tool to identify the closest parcel line to the road, and if it's a corner parcel, use a near table.

Comment: @smiller I do not have an indicator of corner parcels. narrow down selection to each parcel? I would need to to do that for 30k parcels? I am not sure I understand your workflow for this

Comment: @NULL.Dude, I would do the selection using arcpy or perhaps Model Builder.

Comment: Patrick's answer on the post @Andy linked looks useful, with buffering of the roads to identify the parcel frontage.